# How can I update data on MySQL table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I can't seem to trigger `if(isset($_POST['schedule']))` condition via form input button click. How can I update the `$schedule_one` variable using the following code?

```
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $ret= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM maid_marketplace_users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'");
    $num=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
    $nomee = $num['full_name'];
    $schedOne = $num['schedule_one'];
    echo "<p align=center>You are entitled to <b>%10 off</b> for the next <b>12 months.</b></p> ";
?>       
     <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
           <center> <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">Welcome <b>
            <?php
            echo "<br>";
            if (is_null($schedule_one)){
                echo "You don't have any maid services scheduled";
                if(isset($_POST['schedule']))
                {
                    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                    $schedule_one = $_POST['schedule_one'];
                    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE maid_marketplace_users Set schedule_one='$schedule_one' WHERE id='$id'");
                    echo "<script>alert('$id Succes! your next schedule is on $schedule_one');</script>";

                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $schedule_one =  $_POST['schedule_one'];
                echo "Your next schedule is at $schedule_one";
            }
            ?>
            <!--Click here to <a href="logout.php" tite="Logout">Logout. -->
                <form name="schedule" action="" method="post">
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1@s">
                        <div class="uk-inline">
                            <input class="uk-input" name="schedule_one" type="datetime-local">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-width-1-1@s">
                        <input type="submit" name="schedule" value="Schedule" >
                    </div>
                </form>                
            </div></center>
     </div>
    <?php
        die();
        }
```

NOTE: I know you aren't supposed to add password directly into Mysql database, I will encrypt it once it's done.

Comment: I think you need to remove name from the `form` tag, you also use that name in the submit button

Comment: Do you think it may not be triggering because it's inside the if(isset($_POST['login'])) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the `if(isset($_POST['schedule']))` inside of another `if(isset($_POST['login']))` conditional statement. You  have to move it out of the first condition like this;

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
 ....
}
```

and you add the other conditional if statement

```
if(isset($_POST['schedule']))

{
 ....
}
```

One has to finish before you start the other if statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you know you're creating security vulnerabilities.

One thing you would need to do is to not make your SQL update logically unreachable.

In this:

```
                echo "You don't have any maid services scheduled";
                die();
                if(isset($_POST['schedule']))
                {
                    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                    $schedule_one = $_POST['schedule_one'];
                    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE maid_marketplace_users Set schedule_one='$schedule_one' WHERE id='$id'");
                    echo "<script>alert('$id Succes! your next schedule is on $schedule_one');</script>";

                    
                }
```

the `die()` will always interrupt your code before it reaches the SQL update.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I noticed that, removed it but still not working. Do you think it may not be triggering because it's inside the if(isset($_POST['login'])) method?

Comment: Possibly.  If you aren't passing a `login` field via `POST`, none of this will execute.

Comment: I edited my question and added the semi-full version including if(isset($_POST['login'])) which if(isset($_POST['schedule'])) is in it. What to do next

Comment: I can't really tell you, because what you fundamentally need is a concept of what debugging your code consists of.  It's a process of testing your assumptions about what's happening through the use of the code itself or other tools.  I'd recommend an introductory coding class of some kind.